# How to make circle Progress depending on specific time with pause to Timer and Progress?

Tags: android, timer, progress-bar, pause

** Now the problem is:
1-when one percentage finished timer start from  00:00:00
2- when make pause and start again progress increase 1  **

```
private long millisInFuture = 28800000;
private long countDownInterval = 288000;

   int progressBarMaximumValue = (int) (millisInFuture / countDownInterval);
    donutProgress.setMax(progressBarMaximumValue);

btnProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (resumed) {
                resumed = false;
                butnstart.setText("Start");
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimer);
                t = 1;
            } else {
                resumed = true;
                donutProgress.setProgress(pStatus);
                myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
                myCountDownTimer.start();
                runProgress();
            }
        }
    });

 public Runnable updateTimer = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - starttime;
        updatedtime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        secs = (int) (updatedtime / 1000);
        milliseconds = (int) (updatedtime % 1000);
        tv_Time.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", secs / 3600, (secs % 3600) / 60, (secs % 60)));
        handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

check if progress Paused

```
public void runProgress() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (pStatus < 100) {
                if (resumed) {
                    pStatus = i;

                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        donutProgress.setProgress(pStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(countDownInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

CountDownTimer Class

```
      public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        butnstart.setText("Pause");
        starttime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 0);
        t = 0;
        i++;
        donutProgress.setProgress(pStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tv_Time.setText("Task completed");
        donutProgress.setProgress(pStatus);

        if (pStatus == 100) {

            tv_Time.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimer);
            t = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

any help please .
thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVwRU.png)

Comment: why dont you just use a `Handler` and one of its "delayed" methods?

Comment: I really try it but it doesn't working well , Could you please give me example ? @pskink

Comment: create a custom `Handler` and override its `handleMessage` method, from that method you can call `sendEmptyMessageDelayed` method to auto-repeat your task